# Pulling values from a form with php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to pull the values from a form and email them. It is currently emailing just the $to and $subject value but wont send the header or body components. Any help would be appreciated.
Form code:

```
    <body>
    <div class="form-style-6"  >
    <h1>  <img  src="../assets/img/navBar_logo.png"  style = " padding-                              top: 20px;  padding-right:30px; padding-left: 20px;">  Contact Manager</h1>    
    <form action="contactform_email.php" method="get" name="f1">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <textarea name="message" placeholder=""></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>

  and the PHP to pull the values

   <?php

   $to = "manager@plumorchard.com";
   $subject = "Contact Manager";
   $headers = "Reply-To: ".$_GET['email'];
   $body =  "Name : ". $_GET['name']."\n".
   "Email : ". $_GET['email']."\n".
   "Message : ". $_GET['message']."\n".

    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

     ?>

    <b>Thank you for applying online! The apartment manager will get back to   you shortly.</b>
```

Comment: Use post instead of get.

Answer (score 0):

For as far as I know, you need to use a POST request to get a textarea's contents. GET requests won't work on spaced and newlined sentences, since they are directly placed in the url your request points to. POST request makes sure your contents get appended to your HTTP request, so you can actually pull all the info you need out of it.

Note too that this code is not safe at all and is prone to Cross Site Scripting! Always validate user input before handling it.

Comment: I am new to php. What steps should i take to make the code safe. Thx for the input too. Got the code working

Comment: No problem. Take a look at this website: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp Also please tick the answer that helped you fix your code, so other can learn from it too!

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax that is correct, but does something you don't want

```
$body =  "Name : ". $_GET['name']."\n".
"Email : ". $_GET['email']."\n".
"Message : ". $_GET['message']."\n".

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Since mail is contact to the body variable it won't use it, so change your code to this:

```
$body =  "Name : ". $_GET['name']."\n".
"Email : ". $_GET['email']."\n".
"Message : ". $_GET['message']."\n"; // notice I replaced the dot

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

You have had a dot at the end of message that caused this.
You can better use POST instead of GET,

Since sending e-mails is quite complex, use a library like [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org)

Answer (score 0):

Use POST

```
  <form action="contactform_email.php" method="POST" name="f1">
```

And in php

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST)){
 $to = "manager@plumorchard.com";
 $subject = "Contact Manager";
 $headers = "Reply-To: ".$_POST['email'];
 $body =  "Name : ". $_POST['name']."\n".
 "Email : ". $_POST['email']."\n".
 "Message : ". $_POST['message']."\n".

  mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous answers about using POST and the insecurity of the coder, but to offer one thought - you seem to have a trailing dot after your final form field, which will be an issue since it will try to concatenate the next element, which in this case is the mail function, and there is no closing semicolon for the $body element.:

replace the dot with a semicolon on the final portion of the concatenated $body statement.

```
"Message : ". $_GET['message']."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this... add method="post" attribute to the form, and in the php, just to test, have this line : `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` - this should set you on the right path.